# Numbers for diagnostics metrics of VM on portal.azure.com dashboard seem incorrect

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

On *Azure*, I have a **Linux VM**. I enable *Diagnostics settings* on this VM 3 days ago.

**The virtual machine has a 30 GB** disk of which 16 are used. But Azure Monitor chart for **"Filesystem free space" showing** that I have **149 GB** free space and **"Filesystem used space" 24.5 GB**.

Why is that? Is it correct? Can I debug this?

Comment: but you have a temp disk as well, did you account for that?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. This explains everything. I somehow didn't saw that volume with 133 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case this is the expected behaviour due to the temporary disk attached to azure vm

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a custom metric for Diagnostics settings just for single Filesystem volume.

For example via Azure Portal:

- Navigate: *Dashboard > Virtual machines > Link - Diagnostics settings*
- On the opened panel click *Metrics* tab then click *Custom* sub tab and *Add new metric* button

on the opened sub panel fill out the form with:

- class *Filesystem*
- counter *percentofusage* (you may change this on what you are looking for)
- unit *Percent* (again you may change this)
- condition *Name="/"* (here you may change what volume to track)
- choose specifier, */builtin/filesystem/percentusedspace/root* in my case
- display name *Filesystem % used space for Root volume*
- set sample rate in seconds, *30* in my case

[image]

Click save to apply Diagnostics settings.

Then it will possible to create a charts/alerts for your custom Guest VM metric.